# Magento 2.2.6 bin/magento catalog:image:resize taking so much time

Tags: magento2.2.6

After upgrading to Magento 2.2.6 the images are missing. According to devdocs i need to:

> The catalog:image:resize command execution time has been reduced by up to 90% in the release. However, this improvement necessitates these additional steps after upgrading your Magento instance to 2.2.6:
>
> Remove `pub/media/catalog/product/cache` . (Removing this folder frees
>   up space.)
>
> Run `bin/magento catalog:image:resize` to generate a new image cache.
>   (This step is necessary because we’ve changed the path to cached
>   images and must remove the previously cached images.)

The problem is I have more than 120K images and running the command takes so much time, and that is problematic if I want to do it on production.

Any workaround to do it faster?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with high resolution images. Product page load without image cache was taking over 90 seconds! regenerating product images was taking 17 hours! (over 100 000 high resolution images)

Ok, this is not a "standard" but it uses a server redirect to custom php file to create and send an image "on the fly", on a request:

we created a preference for \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image

```
class Image extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image
{

/**
 * Default quality value (for JPEG images only).
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $_quality = 100;


/**
 * @return bool|void
 */
public function isCached()
{
    return true;
}
}
```

This way Magento 2 things product cached image is generated. 
After that we have created a SERVER rewrite for a product image.
Basically we generate images "on the fly" with this nginx setup:

```
[...]
location ~ ^/media/catalog/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    expires +1y;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /media/index.php?$args;
}
[...]
```

This way you don't need to generate images at all, they will be generated when a product page is loaded.

Last part is to add **LazyLoad** for product images and **you do not have to worry about performance** with image processing at all

The trick is to use GD / Imagick to generate a file based on URL which specifies product images.

Answer (score 1):

Magento creates product images thumbnails on demand - that means while someone is browsing your shop - categories, product pages - Magento checks if product image in this size already exists, and if not - it's created.

After removing your images cache directory just don't forget to remove Magento cache deleting **manually** all cache directories contents - var/cache/* var/page_cache/* and so on), and just let them generate itself :)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is create a redirect in nginx. Instead magento load image from cache folder, nginx ignores the folder and loads directly.

```
rewrite /media/catalog/product/cache/[a-z0-9]+/(\S+) /media/catalog/product/$1 last;
```

This nginx regex rule match to any cache folder.

Add the line above in your nginx.conf.sample or your nginx config file like:

```
    ...
    location /media/ {
```

In a store with +200k SKUS I didn't feel **any loss of performance**.

Comment: This would always serve the original product image without resizing it to fit the need. Product listings would use the full size image instead of a smaller thumb which would affect performance and waste bandwidth.